# Get random value without creating `Random` object

Tags: java

I'm writing a class constructor with a decimal field, that is need to be initialized by a random value. Just one little field and I need to create new `Random` object. In the first place it looks cumbersome, and in the second there is can arise a lot of equal values, in case of creating a lot of objects in one time slice (`new Random()` is euqal to `new Random(System.currentTimeMillis())`, and equal timeMillis entails equal random values).

What is the best way to avoid this?

Comment: I'd tried to find solution in `DatagramSocket()` (it needs in random socket value), but hadn't succes.

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: `DatagramSocket` gets system-allocated port numbers from the system, if that's what you mean. They are not random.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> new Random() is euqal to new Random(System.currentTimeMillis())

No, it's not. In recent JDKs, it's `new Random(seedUniquifier() ^ System.nanoTime());`
where seedUniquifier() is based on running a linear congruential generator on a static `AtomicLong`. So it's actually perfectly safe to create `Random` objects as needed.

Of course, you can always have a `private static Random` field and use that in the constructor.

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for [Math.random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29).  This is a static method that implicitly initializes a new `Random` object the first time it is called, and then uses that object thereafter.  So you get the benefits of sharing a single `Random` object between all the static field initializations, without having to manage a `Random` object yourself.

Comment: It has the disadvantage of not having as pleasant an API as `Random` though. There's not a lot of "management" involved in a single static final field...

Comment: It would be great to have equal method for integers. Until then, I prefer to use a **static** `Random` field in my own class.

Answer (score 2):

Are you're using Java 7, `Random` is thread-safe, as documented:

> Instances of java.util.Random are threadsafe. However, the concurrent use of the same java.util.Random instance across threads may encounter contention and consequent poor performance. Consider instead using ThreadLocalRandom in multithreaded designs.

So you *can* just use:

```
private static final Random random = new Random();
```

... or use [`ThreadLocalRandom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) if you're going to be using this from many threads. It's still not going to be as random as [`SecureRandom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) of course. Basically adjust your choice according to your needs.